# Edit Existing Conditional Formats with Code

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

(Excel 2016) I have several large spreadsheets with existing conditional formatting.  On any particular sheet I have several tables each with it's own set of conditional formatting.  The tables change in size so the ranges vary.  And there are lots of them (100's).  The same rules apply to each set, that is, the conditional formatting I want to edit is consistent, with the same "set" of 4 formats that apply to each range/table (e.g. Red/Yellow/Green/Blue).

I'm trying to figure out how to edit a color value in the existing formatting.  For example change a text color that is currently green, to light green.  Right now I have to manually edit hundreds of formula entries.

I've seen lots of examples on applying conditional formatting via VBA, but I don't see how I can step through these tables and edit the existing formats, without changing their order or precedence.

Comment: AFAIK there is not VBA code to check if a cell has conditional formatting applied to it. Hence, you have to try to get it and use at the same time `On Error Resume Next` to circumvent this shortcoming. Similarly, there is no way to determine how many conditional formats are currently in place for any given cell. Once again, you'll have to **try** to grab them an use `On Error Resume Next`. In short: I agree with @Jeeped and the best way is to delete them and redo them rather than trying to write some indirect code with horrible coding practices to overcome VBA's shortcomings in that respect.

Comment: Where is your list of changes? e.g. original color, new color, etc

Comment: I spoke out of turn in an earlier comment. You cannot change the `Formula1` parameter of a CFR but you can adjust the color without destroying and reconstructing it. See below. (@Ralph)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is modify the Fill color, cycle through all of the `.FormatConditions` on the worksheet and use a `Select ... Case` to modify the color ordinal.

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqwqty()
    Dim cfr As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
        For cfr = 1 To .FormatConditions.Count
            With .FormatConditions(cfr).Interior
                Debug.Print .Color
                Select Case .Color
                    Case 255                'dark red
                        .Color = 192        'light red
                    Case 192                'dark red
                        .Color = 255        'light red
                    Case 5287936            'dark green
                        .Color = 5296274    'light green
                    Case 12611584           'dark blue
                        .Color = 15773696   'light blue
                    Case 49407              'orange
                        .Color = 65535      'yellow
                End Select
                Debug.Print .Color
            End With
        Next cfr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  Jeeped:  The code example appears to be what I want to do.  I just need to adjust a color programmatically in all it's instances.  From one to another.  It's the text color in some cases so what does .Interior change to?

Comment: Does the code (Sub wqwqty()) change only the display condition?  I mean:  If I have a condition that results in green text and green interior, and another condition that is red text.  I set up and run the code to change formatconditions of green text to white text.   I have a cell that's condition makes it's text red.  After I run the code, that cell's value changes making it fit the green condition.  Is that cell going to change to the desired green fill with white text or back to the original green on green.  Hopefulyl I worded that clear enough.

Comment: I hope I don't get banned from this site for giving you too many votes per day / week. I heard that one provokes that sort of action when one user push the reputation of another user on this site too much. But then again.. it is not my fault that almost all of your answers are good and worth voting for. Is it?

Comment: @shorton - `.Interior` would be changed to `.Font` if you are changing the font color and not the background color. You would need to stack two Select ... Case statements one after the other's End Select. One would be for `Interior` the other for `.Font`.

Comment: @Ralph - I don't think it will be too long before the SO vote-count algorithm develops sentience and takes over the whole operation in which case we are all doomed anyway. :)